How to access numerical X (formerly Twitter) ID and/or handle during authentication with X?
I am using Auth.js in my NextJS 15 project to authenticate using X. Right now, my src/auth.ts is set up as follows:
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import Twitter from "next-auth/providers/twitter"

// Initialize NextAuth with configuration
export const { handlers, auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
    providers: [
        // Set up Twitter authentication provider
        Twitter,
    ],

    callbacks: {
        // Callback function to log the session object after authentication
        async session({ session, token }) {
            console.log("Twitter session object:", session) // Log the session object
            return session
        },

        // Callback function to check if the user is authorized (logged in)
        authorized: async ({ auth }) => {
            // Return true if authenticated, otherwise redirect to the login page
            return !!auth
        },
    },

    // Custom sign-in page configuration
    pages: {
        signIn: "/login", // Custom login page path
    },
})

The session object returned by X, which I am printing with console.log(), is currently showing only 3 values:
Twitter session object: {
  user: {
    name: 'Some Name',
    email: undefined,
    image: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1234_normal.jpg'
  },
  expires: '2025-01-18T06:41:23.092Z'
}

While I don’t necessarily need the user’s email, I do need their X ID, a numerical value with 19 digits. Is there any way to retrieve this information upon authentication? If not, what is the workaround? Because without a unique identifier from X, how does one store the user’s profile to database? Later if I wish to post something to X in user’s behalf, how would I identify the user’s account without the ID?

Haven't used this but I'll try to help you out. Haven't spent much time looking either so take this for what it's worth.
To be returned by auth it would have to be part of the principal. It looks like it is, and should in fact be included in session.
Anyways it looks like it would have to be part of the principal, because the database lookups to query the full user info would require a key from the principal. And as for keys,

Depending on which user endpoint you use, you can pass either a user ID or a username [so you'll need one of those].

https://developer.x.com/en/docs/x-api/users/lookup/quick-start/user-lookup
Did you remember to configure the provider correctly? Strange it wouldn't return errors if not though~
If you have read all the docs, all the examples, tried minimal reproductions, and don't get an answer here, and then let it cook a couple days and still have nothing, this could be a bug right? Make sure you do all of those things first though, imo. Good luck.

I would have called it a bug and moved on, but there are a number of websites that are still authenticating with X without problem, so it has to be something I’m doing wrong. Just can’t figure out what. The provider configuration I am using is exactly as per Auth.js documentation. And it’s successfully returning the name and image, as you can see. The GET /users/by endpoint that you suggested is for those who have the username and want other details. I need the username itself, so that endpoint doesn’t serve my purpose.
